# How to generate deployment files Azure DevOps - TFVC

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I have hosted ASP.NET Core and .NET Windows application to DevOps Services - TFVC (Cloud)

Now, I am stuck with how to generate deployment files, like debug folder of .NET Windows app or cloud hosting files of ASP.NET Core.

I have created a pipeline to generate deployment files, but how can I execute from the local machine so that developer can get the necessary files to host or install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created a pipeline to generate deployment files, you could add a archive task and a Publish build artifacts task to publish the target files.

Archive files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops

Publish build artifacts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

[image]

[image]

So the developers could download the .zip files from the pipeline summary page to host and use.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks .. is it possible to trigger the pipeline and download the files directly via visual studio without using the web portal ?

Comment: I am afraid you could not do this via visual studio. If you would like to achieve this locally, you could consider Azure CLI:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli

To trigger a pipeline with Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/manage-pipelines-with-azure-cli?view=azure-devops

To download pipeline run artifact:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/runs/artifact?view=azure-cli-latest